# The error was: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credential

Tags: ansible, boto3, boto

Hi i am unable to solve these problem i am getting these , my ansible code is Unable to locate credentials

ansible code

```
---
 - name: main yaml file
   remote_user: ec2-user
   become: yes
   hosts: localhost
   roles:
      - s3
```

roles:

```
- name: basic upload
  s3_sync:
   bucket: s3uploadlocust
   file_root: /home/ec2-user
   include: "*.csv"
   exclude: "*.txt,.*"
   permission: public-read
   file_change_strategy: force
   region: us-east-1
```

Here my environment tools versions:

```
Name: boto3
Version: 1.12.2
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: s3transfer, jmespath, botocore

Name: ansible
Version: 2.9.5
Summary: Radically simple IT automation
Home-page: https://ansible.com/
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info@ansible.com
License: GPLv3+
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: jinja2, PyYAML, cryptography

Python 2.7.16
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: How are you trying to source the credentials ? via env variable via profile ?  Also kindly refer the notes section in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/s3_sync_module.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the module documentation, you can provide 2 more parameters: `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key`.
If they're not set then the value of the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` or `EC2_ACCESS_KEY` environment variable is used for `aws_access_key`.
And `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, or `EC2_SECRET_KEY` environment variable is used for `aws_secret_key`.

Comment: even i tried giving access key and secret key in the code itself after that also im getting the same error